# Can we initialize variables with "nets", instead of a constant, within "initial" block?

Tags: verilog

The following code gives output ("fact") 1 irrespective of the input. What is the error?

```
module Factorial_calc(n, fact);
input [5:0] n;
output reg [64:0] fact;
reg [5:0] i;

initial
begin
i=n;
fact=1;
end

always @(*)
begin
 while(i>0)
 begin
 fact=i*fact;
 i=i-1;
 end
end
```

Comment: An `initial` block runs once at the beginning of your simulation. I think you are expecting it to run more than once at some later times? Are you trying to design hardware?

Comment: No. I'm not using hardware. It's for simulation only. The code is for finding factorial of a number. I want to decrement "n" and multiply with output variable "fact". But since "n" is a "net", I'm using intermediate "reg" "i".

Comment: If it's not hardware, how about putting all this code in a function?

Comment: Yes, of course. There can be better methods. But I want to know what's wrong with the usage.

Comment: Well, I did answer you question, too - "An initial block runs once at the beginning of your simulation. I think you are expecting it to run more than once at some later times?". But, if you're not designing hardware, then you are writing software. Therefore, it makes much more sense to implement this as a function, not as an `always` block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Verilog will not stop you from assign a reg to a net's value within an initial block, but you are extremely unlikely to get the result you expect.

An `initial` block runs ones at time 0. The net may not have the intended value before it is assigned to the reg. By design, Verilog allows for non-determinism of the evaluation order of procedural blocks and contentious assignments within the same phase of a time-step. Verilog's evaluation order can be controlled by event dependency. `initial` blocks do not not event dependencies, so it will always be evaluated as soon as possible. Nets will have dependencies (unless they are assigned to constants) so the typically are evaluated later.

The minimum change to get your code to work is to move the content of the initial block to inside the always block above the while statement. This will update `i` every time input `n` changes and reset `fact` before it is updated in the while loop.

```
always @(*)
begin
  i = n; // <-- local sample
  fact = 1; // local reset
  while(i>0)
  begin
    fact=i*fact;
    i=i-1;
  end
end
```

This will work for simulation, but it cannot synthesize because it used a while statement.

Comment: Yes, I had tried the other way you mentioned. But I wanted to know why won't the first method work. I got the answer. Thank you.

Comment: @Ssap Your first attempt didn't work because `n` hadn't been assigned a value by the time `i=n` was evaluated. And with your original code, `i` will never be updated again after time 0. `i` should be updated whenever `n` changes value, which is what my code does.